# Firebase Cloud Functions: Cannot pass the token retrieved from Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm having issues in retrieving a token saved in realtime database using cloud function's admin.database(). There is only one token to read from the child.

Firebase Database structure

[image]

Here's my code in Index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendNotification = functions.database
.ref('/Logs/{LogsID}')
.onWrite( (change, context) => {
    const notificationSnapshot = change.after.val();
    const status = notificationSnapshot.Status;
    const time = notificationSnapshot.Time;
    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title : status,
            body : time
        }
    }
    console.info(notificationSnapshot);
    const pushToken = admin.database().ref('/Tokens').once('child_added').then( (data) => {
        const tokenSnapshot = data.val();
        const finaltoken = tokenSnapshot.token;
        console.info(finaltoken);
    })

// Need help down here.

    admin.messaging().sendToDevice(finaltoken, payload)
    .then( () => {
        console.log('Notification sent');
    })
    .catch( () =>{
        console.log('Notification failed');
    })
    return null;
});
```

finalToken shows the correct token in log as expected. [Log Showing the token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXfWS.png)

But I'm getting error while I'm passing the same token to admin.messaging(). Console is logging 'Notification sent' but not receiving a notification.

ReferenceError: finaltoken is not defined
    at exports.sendNotification.functions.database.ref.onWrite (/user_code/index.js:43:36)
    at cloudFunctionNewSignature (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:105:23)
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:135:20)
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:827:24
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)

It works when I directly pass the token like,

```
var finalToken = 'ephrj1........kndji'
```

so the admin.messaging() works, only passing the token is not working.

I'm new to Cloud Functions and javascript, so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final token is being retrieved in callback / async function.

That means that when you add it to `.sendToDevice()` the token is undefined because the async function has not retrieved the token from the database... yet.

```
const pushToken = admin.database().ref('/Tokens').once('child_added').then( (data) => {
        const tokenSnapshot = data.val();
        const finaltoken = tokenSnapshot.token;
        console.info(finaltoken);

        admin.messaging().sendToDevice(finaltoken, payload)
        .then( () => {
          console.log('Notification sent');
        })
        .catch( () =>{
          console.log('Notification failed');
        })

       // I moved admin.messaging above this bracket
  })

// It used to be here

return null;
```

Try putting the `admin.messaging` code within the code block of `(data) => {}`

By doing this we ensure that whenever we call `sendToDevice()` the token is defined.

Comment: No problem at all :)