# Notification not being sent via firebase functions. "undefined" logged in console

Tags: javascript, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to send a sample notification to all devices according to their token, however the token is being logged as "undefined" and the notification subsequently fails to deliver

The following lines from my code successfully show me the data from the database:

```
const notificationSnapshot = change.after.val(); //get new value
console.info(notificationSnapshot);
```

However, the following gives "undefined", despite the above retrieving the data successfully.

```
const userToken = notificationSnapshot.token;
console.info(userToken);
```

Is this not the correct way to retrieve the token to send the notification to all the registered devices in my firebase database?

my whole function (**index.js**)

```
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup triggers.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendSampleNotification = functions.database.ref('/User')
.onWrite((change, context) => {
const notificationSnapshot = change.after.val(); //get new value
const userToken = notificationSnapshot.token;
const name = notificationSnapshot.name;
const surname = notificationSnapshot.surname;

console.info(notificationSnapshot);
console.info(userToken);

var message = {
notification: {
title: 'test title',
body: 'test message'
},
token: userToken
};
admin.messaging().send(message).then((response) => {
console.log("Message sent successfully:", response);
return response;
})
.catch((error) => {
console.log("Error sending message: ", error);
});
});
```

Comment: Can you show the object you write under the `User` node? In other words, what do you get with `console.info(notificationSnapshot);`? Are you sure that this object has a token property?

Comment: All the indentation of your code is lost, making it difficult to read. :-( It would be helpful if you went back, pasted it, and formatted it again with triple backticks to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Also it appears you are not returning a promise that resolves when all the async work is complete in the function.  Simply calling then/catch on a promise isn't good enough for Cloud Functions to handle it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that your issue is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55219989/firebase-cloud-functions-cannot-pass-the-token-retrieved-from-realtime-database?rq=1) since you are having a missing token (showed as undefined) due to the executions times, more or less what Doug was pointing out.

Note that the solution relies on considering the execution times and I’ve seen also that the implementation differs in some method executions but I would say the generals point in the same direction.